Is centrifugal force in this case thrust force?
If I stand on skateboard and swing heavy bucket back and forth doing arc of 90 degrees, can centrifugal force move skateboard forward or all forces cancel out so resultant force is zero?
edited: forward to the right


I think that as long as you hold on to the bucket, the net forces will be zero. But if you swing and let go of the bucket, then there will be some net force acting on you and the bucket, causing you to move in the direction of your force.

If the wheels of the skateboard were ratchets, (i.e., If some mechanism allowed them to rotate one way, but not the opposite way) then swinging that bucket would be an effective means of propelling the board.

@SolomonSlow In which position  skate move forward and  which backward,  1 to 2, 2 to 3? Centrifugal force dont act here as thrust force, what is reason for moving?

Explaining the ratchets is easier in just one dimension. Imagine, instead of swinging the bucket in an arc, you hold it at chest level, and alternate pushing it out and pulling it back. When you push on the bucket, it pushes on you. (Newton's 3rd law) The force on you is transmitted through you, through the locked ratchets, to the ground, and the ground pushes back equally because it cannot move. The net force on you is zero, and so you do not move. When you pull, the ratchets release, force on you from the bucket is unbalanced, and so it accelerates you forward as you pull the bucket back.

FYI: I am not going to use the word, "centrifugal." That word refers to a way of understanding the laws of mechanics in a rotating coordinate system. There is no need to use a rotating coordinate system here. It would only complicate things. Finding a problem in which it helps to use rotating coordinates (or, coordinates that are accelerated in any other way) is unusual. Most problems are more easily understood from the viewpoint of an inertial coordinate system.

The short answer is that there will be no net propulsion. Newton's third law dictates that action is equal to reaction. If the bucket was thrown and released off the front of the skateboard, the board would be propelled backward. The momentum gained by the bucket is equal in magnitude and opposite to the momentum gained by the skateboard. In the example given in the OP the bucket is initially accelerated towards the front as the bucket is accelerated from position 1 to 2, the skateboard would move a short distance backward, but as the bucket continues from position 2 to position 3, the bucket is accelerated towards the back and the reaction is that the skateboard is accelerated forward, back to where it started. In summary, the skate board would just oscillate forwards and backwards and get nowhere.
For there to be a resultant net forward motion of the skateboard, something else has to gain the same net amount of momentum in the opposite direction, which is not the case here.
As SolomonSlow mentioned in the comments, if the wheels had ratchets, it would be possible to use this method to propel the skateboard forward. As the bucket moves from 1 to 2 the wheel ratchets prevent the board moving. As the bucket continues from 2 to 3, the ratchets allow the skateboard to react by moving to the right and  gain in the forward direction. The third law still applies with the ratchet wheels. When the bucket moves from right to left from position 1 to position  2, the ratchets prevent the board moving relative to the Earth and now the reaction is the Earth moving a very slowly to the left. The third law of "action always being equal to reaction" means the total linear momentum of the universe always remains the same. Whenever something gains momentum in one direction, something else has to gain the same amount of momentum in the opposite direction.

Forward skate motion is  at my photo to the right?

@22flower Other way. To the left.

@22flower The first part, from position 1 to 2 is equivalent to throwing a bucket off the back (to the right) but the the motion from 3 to 2 undoes that.

Please edit your answer as forward to the right, it doesnt make sense that forward is to the left  in contex of my question, because centrifugal force("thurst") is to the right...

@22flower I have edited my answer to agree with the new definition of forward since you have altered your diagram. Bear in mind we can force what we want to be the forward direction by which way the ratchets operate. In the case where there are no ratchets, there is no net motion and forward cannot be defined in that case except by nominating a convention.

Also bear in mind that propellent always moves in the opposite direction to the net thrust, eg in the case of a rocket, the combustion products are ejected out the back to cause the forward motion. In the skateboard case, the bucket is the propellant and the board reacts in the opposite direction.


@SolomonSlow I understand with case push and pull bucket, but don't really understand in my case, when will skate go forward and when backward?

In my comment (above) I asked you to imagine yourself holding the bucket at chest height and alternating between pushing it out, away from your chest, and pulling it back. That motion simulates the horizontal component of the two dimensional forces on and motion of the swinging bucket.
If you don't swing the bucket with enough force to actually lift yourself off of the ground (That's pretty hard to imagine) then there will be no vertical component to your motion. The motion that you are asking about will be purely one-dimensional. So that's why I think you can ignore the vertical components of the swinging bucket, and just picture yourself pushing and pulling on it.

If you stand on an ideal skateboard, on an ideal, level plain, then the horizontal momentum of the bucket-you-skateboard system must be conserved. If the center of mass (COM) of the system is stationary, then nothing you can do with the bucket will change that. The COM must remain stationary because any change in its position could only be accomplished by some change in its momentum. (Maybe only a temporary change, but even a temporary change is not allowed.)
When you push the bucket away from yourself, the bucket pushes back (Newton's 3rd law). Because of the ideal behavior of the skateboard, there are no other forces acting on you. You push only against the bucket's momentum—you accelerate the bucket away from you, and it pushes back against your momentum. It accelerates you in the opposite direction. Same thing happens when you pull, except the directions are reversed.
Every time the bucket moves one way, you and the board move in the opposite way, and in an amount that causes the skateboard-you-bucket COM not to move at all. Since your pushing and pulling is periodic, so is the motion. In the long run, you go nowhere.

If we go back to the picture of you swinging the bucket, then there's a vertical component to everything as well. But then, the ground plays a very important role. The ground cannot move, so the ground always exerts an upward force on you that exactly cancels out the downward force that you exert on the ground. So long as there is no upward force on you that is greater than your own weight (again, very unlikely) you will not move up or down.

First of all, I'm confused by you labelling going to the left as "forward". The centrifugal "force" will be to the right.
As to the meat of the question, centrifugal "force" generally refers to the pseudo force that appears when having a coordinate system of uniform circular motion; that is, there is motion of a constant angular velocity. If the angular velocity is constant, then there is no tangential acceleration. All of the acceleration is radial, that is, towards the center. But if you're swinging the bucket back and forth, then you don't have constant angular velocity. You do have tangential acceleration, or, in other words, a torque.
For instance, if the bucket is going from 2 to 3, then there's a counterclockwise torque on the bucket, and that torque will have a component to the right. Since you are applying a force to the right on the bucket the right, you experience a force to the left from the bucket.
Through one cycle of swinging the bucket back and forth, the bucket ends up with the same velocity as it started with, so the total acceleration, and total momentum transfer, is zero. Unless there are some forces between the "skateboard, person, and bucket" system, such as friction, rachets, etc., the velocity of the center of the mass of that system can't change. So while the skateboard will move back and forth, if it started with zero velocity then it won't have any net change in position over a cycle.

I label forward to the left because @KDP call it like this in his answer..Yes but that dont make sense in context to my question, so I will edit it..

You're standing on a skate board, and swing a heavy bucket. Can this move you?
It depends on two things. The direction to rotation of the bucket, and the coefficient of friction, $\mu$, between the wheels of the skateboard and the ground.
Further, I'll assume the friction is small enough that a small force is enough to overcome it.
If you swing the bucket in the vertical plane(this is not what is shown, I presume), then the initial forward swing would propel you forward, and the backward swing would do similarly in the opposite direction. This is similar to how one would swing on  a swing.
If you swing the bucket horizontally(as shown, I presume), it would be hard to get the skateboard moving, in the sense that you would need a lot of angular momentum, and it must stop quickly, i.e., you can't take it backwards. In that case, Yes, it would be possible, just difficult.
Note that we didn't consider what would happen in a frictionless surface. Assume you're standing(without a skateboard) on a frictionless surface. Now, regardless of how you swing the bucket, there is no way to get you to move in any direction. Can you guess why? Hint: Draw the free body diagram of a person on (say) a frozen lake($\mu = 0$).
